# On the theory of code replication

Tags: html, css

I have started work in a class for school where the professor give us a few images of a webpage and asks us to replicate it with certain constraints.  The first assignment is to create the web page with nothing but HTML and CSS, I know the basics of both and was wondering this:

1. **When faced with a font/shading of text what is the best way to go about replicating it in CSS?** The title bar has some formatting that I do not know where to even begin replicating.
2. **Secondly can you, with html, make a horizontal table and fill it with images?**

Comment: The first question isn't clear for me. The answer to the second one is clearly yes : Google for "html table" or try to type `<table><tr><td><img src=somesrc></td><td><img src=someothersrc></td></tr></table>`.

Comment: Does this project target specific browsers? (For example, does it need to support IE6 and up?) Or does it specify using HTML5 or CSS3?

Comment: The project is going to work with HTML5 and CSS3 I believe, we are not allowed to use any jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to copy the site and stylesheet and perhaps javascript and say here it is, but that may be cheating :-)

> When faced with a font/shading of text what is the best way to go about replicating it in CSS?

There is the [`text-shadow`](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow) property, but not all browsers support it. You can always use images or just drop the text-shadow requirement.

> The title bar has some formatting that I do not know where to even begin replicating.

Rightmouse clikc inspect element and see how it is done. This is for Chrome. For FF you would have to install FireBug.

> Secondly can you, with html) make a horizontal table and fill it with images?

Yes you can and no you shouldn't. Tables should be used for tabular data and you are using it for layout. Use CSS and perhaps `div`s when needed.

Comment: Thank you for the responce, it's just going to be a pain to move each individual image with CSS haha, in addition the source code is unreachable since the project was given with a set of jpgs.

Answer (score 0):

> When faced with a font/shading of text what is the best way to go about replicating it in CSS?

CSS3 provides several properties to deal with text formatting, such as `text-shadow` and `@font-face`.

> Secondly can you (with html) make a horizontal table and fill it with images?

Yes, why not? If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a single row table, i.e., a single `<tr>` with `<td>`s inside, each one containing an `<img>` element. But beware: if you want the table just to layout the images side-by-side, it's bad practice. You should just add all `<img>` one after another, or use `display: inline` or `inline-block`, or use floats.

Comment: Ah I will look into that, I would rather not get into any bad practices while completing work for this class.